# How do I convert HTML to a Word document on the fly in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ms-word, converters

I have an HTML string I would like to convert into a word document and download upon a button click.

I know how to download a file, so that's not part of the question - just some context.

I've been unable to find any libraries or code examples that do this apart from implementing my own OpenXML solution.

I am able to download it as an .rtf file just fine - but it's specifically the .docx format that is giving me trouble.

Comment: If you could comment as to why you downvoted or closed - please let me know.  If you view my history, I'm not a help vampire.  I genuinely can't find anything.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."  This is a very specific question, not a recommendation like "how do I build a website?"  Please provide some reason so I can either improve or delete the question.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Ryios I'm not looking for software to do this - I am trying to write C# code that will package it up in the .docx container that can be opened by someone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[`.NetFiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iVmbjU)***

In order to build the .doc file (which supports html) you are going to need to format the html to include indicators that office understands, and then you will need to write that format to the response.

This approach was inspired by the post at codeproject in vb http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7341/Dynamically-generate-a-MS-Word-document-using-HTML and is mostly verbatim but translated to c#

```
//build the content for the dynamic Word document
//in HTML alongwith some Office specific style properties. 
var strBody = new StringBuilder();

strBody.Append("<html " +
 "xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' " +
 "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'" +
  "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>" +
  "<head><title>Time</title>");

//The setting specifies document's view after it is downloaded as Print
//instead of the default Web Layout
strBody.Append("<!--[if gte mso 9]>" +
 "<xml>" +
 "<w:WordDocument>" +
 "<w:View>Print</w:View>" +
 "<w:Zoom>90</w:Zoom>" + 
 "<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>" +
 "</w:WordDocument>" +
 "</xml>" +
 "<![endif]-->");

strBody.Append("<style>" +
 "<!-- /* Style Definitions */" +
 "@page Section1" +
 "   {size:8.5in 11.0in; " +
 "   margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in ; " +
 "   mso-header-margin:.5in; " +
 "   mso-footer-margin:.5in; mso-paper-source:0;}" +
 " div.Section1" +
 "   {page:Section1;}" +
 "-->" +
 "</style></head>"); 

 strBody.Append("<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>" +
  "<div class=Section1>");
 strBody.Append(yourCustomHTMLString);
 strBody.Append("</div></body></html>");

//Force this content to be downloaded 
//as a Word document with the name of your choice
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
Response.AppendHeader ("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myword.doc");

Response.Write(strBody.ToString());
```

Comment: how to store this doc object in another file because I need to convert this doc file to pdf..